# Recursive Function Call in OOP Python

Tags: python, oop, recursion

So I've recently started doing Object Oriented Programming with Python, and for a specific problem I have to write a class that deals with fractions.  Everything seems to be coming along fine with writing methods of common math operators such as subtraction and addition; however, I am stuck with a recursive method.

```
class fractions():
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
    def GreatestCommonDivisor(self, numerator, denominator): # This is the culprit
        if numerator%denominator == 0:
            return denominator
        else:
            return GreatestCommonDivisor(self, denominator, numerator%denominator)
```

When I call the Greatest Common Divisor function in another method that needs the to find the greatest divisor of the numerator, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 9, in GreatestCommonDivisor
NameError: global name 'GreatestCommonDivisor' is not defined
```

I call the function like this:

```
X = fractions(9, 36)
X.GreatestCommonDivisor(X.numerator, X.denominator)
```

If someone could tell me what the issue here is and how to fix it I would greatly appreciate it, this is my first usage of a recursive function in a class.

Comment: If you're going to use camelCase, you should have your classes start with a capital and your methods start with lowercase. Eg `class Fractions`. `def greatestCommonDivisor`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This line is where the NameError occurs:

```
return GreatestCommonDivisor(self, denominator, numerator%denominator)
```

It should read:

```
return self.GreatestCommonDivisor(denominator, numerator % denominator)
```

Answer (score 2):

GreatestCommonDivisor is an instance method, not a global method. You need to do

```
return self.GreatestCommonDivisor(denominator, numerator%denominator)
```

But your code seems to show you don't really have object oriented concepts completely grasped yet.

Comment: I would totally agree, I just started looking at object oriented material about two days ago, so this is the first piece of oop code I'm attempting on my own.  It will be a bit of time before I take an actual course that strictly focuses on OOP.  I would like to learn the concepts before then.  So any advice would be very helpful, thanks.